# shutil.copytree copy along with source directory name as well

Tags: python, shutil, copytree

**Folder1:**

```
tree
.
├── abc.json
├── pqr.bson
├── subdir
│   ├── abc.json
│   ├── pqr.bson
│   └── xyz.json
└── xyz.json
```

1 directory, 6 files

```
import os
import shutil
sourcefolder="./Folder1"
destinationfolder="./Folder2"    
if os.path.exists(destinationfolder):
    shutil.rmtree(destinationfolder)
shutil.copytree(sourcefolder,destinationfolder)
```

**Folder2:**

```
tree
.
├── abc.json
├── pqr.bson
├── subdir
│   ├── abc.json
│   ├── pqr.bson
│   └── xyz.json
└── xyz.json
```

1 directory, 6 files

I would like copy along with source folder as well something like below under Folder2:

**Folder2:**

```
    tree
├── Folder1
│   ├── abc.json
│   ├── pqr.bson
│   ├── subdir
│   │   ├── abc.json
│   │   ├── pqr.bson
│   │   └── xyz.json
│   └── xyz.json
```

Is there a way we can do this with in `copytree` ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and I used Pathlib.

```py
from path import Pathlib
import shutil

shutil.copytree(sourcefolder, destinationfolder / sourcefolder.name)
```